# Angular2 TypeScript - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript1.7

The version of my TypeScript `1.7.5`

#### My main component file

```
// import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
// import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

    @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        // template: '<h1>My title: {{title}}</h1> <h2>Hardcoded h2</h2>'
    })
    @View({
        templateUrl: '/templates/home.html',
        directives: []
    })
    .Class({
        constructor: function() {

        }
    })

export class AppComponent {
    title = "My First Angular 2 App";
}
```

#### My HTML scripts

```
<!-- 1. Load libraries -->
<script src="node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

<script src='app.component.js'></script>
<script src='app/boot.js'></script>
```

Next when I try to compile the file `tsc app.component.ts --module system --experimentalDecorators`

**I get the following error:** `app.component.ts(2,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/core'.`

Do you know what I'm missing here?

Comment: Try adding the template or templateUrl in the  `@Component` annotation instead

Comment: and remove the `.Class({
        constructor: function() {

        }
    })` stuff, that's not from a typescript example is it? your class is: `export class AppComponent {
    title = "My First Angular 2 App";
}`

Comment: Ok I removed `@View` and moved the `templateUrl` to `@Componant`, but still when trying to compile it I get `Cannot find module 'angular2/core'` Also isn't `.Class({ contructor: function()` the place where I can add logic? Do have have any sample code for a similar basic structure?

Comment: like I said your class is `export class AppComponent` that's where you add your logic, you can set the constructor on it.

Comment: Check the second example @ https://angular.io/

Comment: Ok I found the 2nd example, and I just replaced the code it works now, their `System.config` was different that what I had, also I think I needed the latest scripts that the Google team is using, this had that http://plnkr.co/edit/DNmmOxUzBOdbsD4eTZER?p=preview Want to post answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove:

```
.Class({
    constructor: function() {

    }
})
```

Remove:

```
@View({
    templateUrl: '/templates/home.html',
    directives: []
})
```

and put `templateUrl: '/templates/home.html',` in the @Component annotation instead.

And apply the `system.js` configuration.
In general follow the steps in here:

https://angular.io/

Check the second example.